# How to programmatically detect port already in use in Tomcat webapp?

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, port, bind

I supply my customers with my Tomcat webapp, which is configured to listen on port 80 and runs on their Windows PCs.

In some of their deployments, Microsoft's World Wide Web Publishing Service is already running unintentionally, which also listens on port 80.  Thus when Tomcat and my webapp is launched, an **Address already in use: JVM_Bind** exception message is logged to the console, however it is scrolled off the screen by later startup messages and is thus unnoticed.

**My Question**: Is there some way to either

- Configure the Tomcat server to stop under such circumstances, or
- Code my webapp to **detect this and stop?**  If my webapp could detect this, I would then log a message about what steps the user should take to kill the other program.  Hopefully the message would remain visible on the console and not scroll off the screen.

  > ```
  > netstat -a -o -n | findstr 0.0:80
  > taskkill /F /PID *pid*
  > ```

While I have user documentation describing the problem and remedy, it's not usually handy.  My thinking is that if this were the last message on the console, it may reduce the support call time.

Answer (score 2):

Your application will start to be deployed into servlet container after IO (Http/Ajp connectors) is already started, so there is no way how you can do this from web application.

You can however wrap Tomcat startup script with batch file which will do that for you (and print meaningful error message, then wait for user to press enter).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  That was my thinking as well.

I was hoping someone knew of an org.apache.catalina method that my webapp could call that might reveal status.

Comment: @KenLin : what kind of `status` you would like to reveal? Ports used by Tomcat instance? There is easy way to do this, but it will not help you for reason described in my answer

Comment: If my webapp could find the port successfully (or not) bound by Tomcat that would help.  It seems like this would be part of org.apache.catalina.

Comment: Hmm, I'm thinking about this again.  

I suppose I could have my webapp try to make a localhost request to itself and see if it is successful.  Thoughts on what gotchas I might face with this approach?